# Need query to display the departments which are having both MALE and FEMALE Employees

Tags: oracle

Need query to display the departments which are having both MALE and FEMALE Employees

```
CREATE TABLE departments(deptname VARCHAr2(20),sex VARCHAR2(2));

INSERT INTO departments VALUES('SALES','M');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES('SALES','F');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES('SALES','M');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES('SALES','F');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES('ENG','M');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES('ENG','F');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES('MKT','M');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES('CLE','F');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES('AUTO','M');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES('AUTO','M');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES('ENV','F');
INSERT INTO departments VALUES('ENV','F');


Expected Output
Deptname   Sex
SALES      M
SALES      F
SALES      M
SALES      F
ENG        M
ENG        F
```

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Or using a windowing function to avoid hitting the table twice:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT d.*,
               COUNT(DISTINCT sex) OVER (PARTITION BY deptname) sex_count
          FROM departments d)
 WHERE sex_count > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select *
from departments
where deptname in (
  select deptname from departments 
  group by deptname having count(distinct sex) > 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks friends for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
SELECT deptname, sex
FROM   departments
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY deptname
  ORDER BY sex
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (^ female+ male+ $)
  DEFINE
    female AS sex = 'F',
    male   AS sex = 'M'
);
```

Which outputs:

| DEPTNAME | SEX |
| --- | --- |
| ENG | F |
| ENG | M |
| SALES | F |
| SALES | F |
| SALES | M |
| SALES | M |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6Q9rmv5B)